# How to change dynamic data-src for lazy images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have hover list box and my list box has some links if I visit links my main image of list box is changing with relevant image but I'm using lazy load plugin that is why I want to change with `data-src` not `src` but it didn't work how can I handle as dynamic ?

and one more thing I guess it's possible bot how I don't know..if I leave area my images must change with default images but I couldn't

My main structure

HTML

```
      <div class="tur-list-box">

        <div class="tur-list-content">
            <figure>
              <img data-src="img/assets/tourlist-2.jpg" class="lazy" src="img/assets/placeholder.png" alt="tur sayfası">
              <a href="#" class="figure-overlay">
                  <p class="tour-price">
                    <span class="price-big">73,</span>
                    <span class="price-little">40</span>
                    <span class="price-unit">TL*</span>
                    <span class="price-block">‘den itibaren</span>
                  </p>
              </a>
            </figure><!-- tur resim-->

            <div class="tur-details">
              <h3><a href="#">Hafta Sonu Turları</a></h3>
              <p>15 farklı program</p>
              <i class=" open-tur-toggle fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div><!-- tur detay-->

        </div><!-- tur list content-->

        <div class="tur-list-toggle">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><a href="#" data-img="http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/resimler/orta/2016-02/otel_buyuk-abant-oteli_vPYKBnet58y0itPrkpce.jpg">Kakava ( Hıdırellez ) Şenlikleri Alaçatı <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-img="http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/resimler/orta/2016-10/otel_abant-palace-hotel_FTfyg8HYVB9lNeOUMA76.jpg">Ot Festivali Urla Enginar Festivali Turu <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-img="http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/resimler/normal/2016-01/tur_adana-portakal-cicegi-karnavali_3eO46CjOg4k34ooQM2mA.jpg">Adana Portakal Çiçeği Karnavalı Isparta <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-img="http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/resimler/normal/2016-01/tur_isparta-goller-yoresi-gul-hasadi-turu_Ue7lCTZhtuNk6DHTOy5C.jpg">Gül Hasadı Ve Göller Yöresi Turları <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-img="http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/resimler/normal/2016-03/tur_manisa-mesir-macunu-senligi-turu_ElEY2IdzFOfHLe6do7ja.jpg">Manisa Mesir Macunu Şenliği Turu <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-img="http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/resimler/normal/2016-01/tur_isparta-goller-yoresi-gul-hasadi-turu_KN8aDpGyF4O6gKABF5d4.jpg">Uçaklı Festival Turları <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- acilir kapanir alan-->

      </div><!-- tur list box-->
```

and JS

```
 $(".tur-list-box").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".tur-list-toggle").stop().slideDown();
    $(this).find(".open-tur-toggle").stop().removeClass("fa-chevron-down").addClass("fa-chevron-up");
  },function(){
    $(this).find(".tur-list-toggle").stop().slideUp();
    $(this).find(".open-tur-toggle").stop().removeClass("fa-chevron-up").addClass("fa-chevron-down");
    var defaultImg = $(this).find("figure img").attr("data-src");
    console.log(defaultImg);
  });


$('.tur-list-toggle ul li a').hover(
    function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();  
      var getAttr = $(this).attr("data-img");
      $(this).parents(".tur-list-box").find("figure img").attr("src",getAttr);
      $(this).fadeIn(500);
    },
    function(e) {

    }
);
```

if you hover image you gonna see link and if you visit the links images has been change
[and you can see the demo](http://firatabak.com/test/tur-anasayfa.html)

Comment: Could u pls explain a bit better?

Comment: Ok.all link has a data-img attribute and if I hover the links my top image is chancing but I don't wanna change src of img I wanna change data-src of image but it's not chancing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
$(this).parents(".tur-list-box").find("figure img").attr("src",getAttr);
```

to

```
$(this).parents(".tur-list-box").find("figure img").data("src",getAttr);
```

more on [data](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data)

Comment: no I mean I'm using lazy load images and it gave me a attribute(data-src) to add.but I want to change data-src attribute not src attribute

Comment: yes `data()` changes only those attributes starting with `data-`

Comment: you can also use `attr('data-src',getAttr)` there but sometimes it has bugs. this function is built just for doing data-val manipulation

Comment: Are you sure of having added jquery? see the console (F12) for any errors

Comment: I'm sure I added but you cannot see on console but if you check out source code you will see :)